# How can I access a URL using python requests when the page changes when I request it, even though the parameters are in the URL?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the following website: 
http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable_batter_vs_pitcher.jsp#season=2018&batting_team=119&batter=571771&pitching_team=133&pitcher=641941

(this is an example URL with a certain pitcher/batter matchup)

I'm able to  enter the player codes and team codes easily with this function:

```
def matchupURL(season, batter, batterTeam, pitcher, pitcherTeam):
return "http://mlb.mlb.com/stats/sortable_batter_vs_pitcher.jsp#season=" + str(season)+ "&batting_team="+str(teamNumDict[batterTeam])+"&batter="+str(batter)+"&pitching_team="+str(teamNumDict[pitcherTeam])+"&pitcher="+str(pitcher);
```

which works nicely, and the returned string works when pasted into my browser.

But when i make a request a la

```
newURL = matchupURL(2018,i.id,x.home_team,j.id,x.away_team)
        print(i+ " vs " + j)
        newSes = requests.get(newURL);
        html = BeautifulSoup(newSes.text, "lxml")
        mydivs = html.findAll("td",{"class":"dg-ops"})
        #do something with this div
```

I'm unable to find the div. Infact, the entire format of the HTML returned changes. Further, adding headers didnt help, nor did using urllib instead of requests.

Comment: The browser is probably rendering html elements via JS, which isn't run when using something like `requests`. You should consider using something that will render a page like a browser. Have you considered headless Chrome or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page is a dynamic, i.e., the content is dynamically generated by javascript and showed in the front. That is the reason you can't detect the `div` tag.

But in this case you can scrape easier. With inspect tool from your browser you can detect that the data comes from a GET request to an URL. For your example, you only have to provide the players id :

```
import requests
url = 'http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.stats_batter_vs_pitcher_composed.bam'
params = {"sport_code":"'mlb'","game_type":"'R'","player_id":"571771","pitcher_id":"641941"}
resp = requests.get(url, params=params).json()
print(resp)
```

That prints:

```
{'stats_batter_vs_pitcher_composed': {'stats_batter_vs_pitcher_total': {'queryResults': {'created': '2018-04-12T22:21:47', 'totalSize': '1', 'row': {'hr': '1', 'gidp': '0', 'pitcher_first_last_html': 'Emilio Pagán', 'player': 'Hernandez, Enrique', 'np': '4', 'sac': '0', 'pitcher': 'Pagan, Emilio', 'rbi': '1', 'player_first_last_html': 'Enrique Hernández', 'tb': '4', 'bats': 'R', 'xbh': '1', 'bb': '0', 'slg': '4.000', 'avg': '1.000', 'pitcher_id': '641941', 'ops': '5.000', 'hbp': '0', 'pitcher_html': 'Pagán, Emilio', 'g': '', 'd': '0', 'so': '0', 'throws': 'R', 'sf': '0', 'tpa': '1', 'h': '1', 'cs': '0', 'obp': '1.000', 't': '0', 'ao': '0', 'r': '1', 'go_ao': '-.--', 'sb': '0', 'player_html': 'Hernández, Enrique', 'sbpct': '.---', 'player_id': '571771', 'ibb': '0', 'ab': '1', 'go': '0'}}}, 'copyRight': ' Copyright 2018 MLB Advanced Media, L.P.  Use of any content on this page acknowledges agreement to the terms posted here http://gdx.mlb.com/components/copyright.txt  ', 'stats_batter_vs_pitcher': {'queryResults': {'created': '2018-04-12T22:21:47', 'totalSize': '1', 'row': {'hr': '1', 'gidp': '0', 'pitcher_first_last_html': 'Emilio Pagán', 'player': 'Hernandez, Enrique', 'np': '4', 'sac': '0', 'pitcher': 'Pagan, Emilio', 'rbi': '1', 'opponent': 'Oakland Athletics', 'player_first_last_html': 'Enrique Hernández', 'tb': '4', 'xbh': '1', 'bats': 'R', 'bb': '0', 'avg': '1.000', 'slg': '4.000', 'pitcher_id': '641941', 'ops': '5.000', 'hbp': '0', 'pitcher_html': 'Pagán, Emilio', 'g': '', 'd': '0', 'so': '0', 'throws': 'R', 'sport': 'MLB', 'sf': '0', 'team': 'Los Angeles Dodgers', 'tpa': '1', 'league': 'NL', 'h': '1', 'cs': '0', 'obp': '1.000', 't': '0', 'ao': '0', 'season': '2018', 'r': '1', 'go_ao': '-.--', 'sb': '0', 'opponent_league': 'AL', 'player_html': 'Hernández, Enrique', 'sbpct': '.---', 'player_id': '571771', 'ibb': '0', 'ab': '1', 'opponent_id': '133', 'team_id': '119', 'go': '0', 'opponent_sport': 'MLB'}}}}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a student but I haven't taken a networking class yet, hopefully there I'll learn in more detail how to solve problems like this.

Comment: One note for future viewers: I think it should be .json() not just .json Thats what worked for me, its a method.